# Sending email from Wordpress (not localhost)

Tags: php, wordpress, email, plugins

i'm making a plugin in php and after submit the form, sending an email to the filler. Is there any tutorial that shows how to send email from wordpress not on localhost? or a normal command [mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers)] is enough to run

Comment: Where is your Wordpress installation when "not on localhost"?

Comment: i mean he is not on my PC.

Comment: That leaves the rest of all the computers in the world. I don't need a location, but something like the OS, hosting provider, PHP version, and specifically which [Mail Delivery Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_delivery_agent) you are using.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Comment: its seohost.pl and im not using any MDA because i had no idea about this. Thats why im here

Comment: As noted, use WordPress's function for this. Since you appear to be new to this, just as an FYI, your plugin's role is _not_ to send email, but instead to submit the email to WordPress to send. That's a big distinction. As long as you call that function using the correct parameters, if someone doesn't receive it, it is up to the site owner/developer/host to fix/troubleshoot.